# error message in Xcode v 6.3.2

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm getting this error message in relation to the exclamation mark at the end of this line:

```
sound1.URL = soundURL!
```

> "Cannot assign a value of type ‘NSURL’ to a value of type ‘NSURL’
>   Type"

I've googled this issue and looked at a couple of explanations for this error code but I still can't work out what's wrong. Can anyone help?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SoundListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var sounds: [Sound] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        var soundPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("mhsTesting", ofType: "m4a")
        var soundURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPath!)

        var sound1 = Sound()
        sound1.name = "Michael"
        sound1.URL = soundURL!

        self.sounds.append(sound1)

    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `Sound` class

Answer (score 0):

This is your `Sound class`?

```
class Sound{
    var name: String?
    var URL : NSURL.Type?
}
```

Try with code below:

```
class Sound{
    var name: String?
    var URL : NSURL?
}
```